# SmartBreadCrumbs - using route values with parent level

Tags: c#, .net-core, breadcrumbs

Started using smartbreadcrumbs in core 3.1 and all good until i needed to setup a parent crumb.
The parent needs a routeValue of the Id, this is a parameter passed into the child (Upgrade) action.

example:
Home / **Product** / Upgrade

**Product** url should be /member/product/**12345**

Can this be achieved with SmartbreadCrumbs?
I have this working but not passing the routeValue.

```
[Breadcrumb("Upgrade", FromAction = "Product", FromController = typeof(MemberController))]
```

Also it seems like setting a breadcrumbNode no longer works:

```
new BreadcrumbNode(product.Category.Name, "Controller", "Category", null, new { id = 10 });
```

Regards

Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to zHaytam for this answer.

So, you simply need to code this in your action:

```
  var childNode1 = new MvcBreadcrumbNode("Product", "Member", "Product", false)
        {
            RouteValues = new { id } //this comes in as a param into the action
        };

        var childNode2 = new MvcBreadcrumbNode(action, controller, title)
        {
            OverwriteTitleOnExactMatch = true,
            Parent = childNode1
        };

        ViewData["BreadcrumbNode"] = childNode2;
```

Here's a link to more info:
https://github.com/zHaytam/SmartBreadcrumbs/wiki/4.-Manual-nodes